# Java: Object to double "hash" function with uniform distribution on [0,1)

Tags: java, random, distribution, hashcode

I'm trying to build or find a function that takes java objects as an input and returns a double value in the [0,1) interval. Cryptographic security (one-way-function, no collision) of the "hash" function is not my main concearn. I simply want uniformly distributed double value between 0 and 1.

I can't use functions or classes like Math.random or Random since that would return different results for the same input.

My best approach so far was using the Object.hashCode() method and breaking the returned int-value down to a double between 0 and 1. Unfortunately, the distribution of the resulting values is not very uniformly. Lots of values are between 0.1 and 0.3. I guess the hashCode() method isn't unifomrly distributed.

Any ideas on how to improve my approach or for a better approach in general?

Comment: Also, the values that `Object.hashCode()` returns will likely differ between runs of a program (for the same input). Do you want reproducibility between runs, too?

Comment: Are objects that you use as input unifomrly distributed?

Comment: It is bad idea to use values of hashCode() in any mathematical manipulation. What problem you try to solve?

Comment: I don't need reproducibility between runs.
The objects are not uniformly distributed.
I'm trying to implement a dynamic DeBruijn graph. Each node in this graph is assigned a "hash" value between 0 and 1. So the input are objects of my node-class.

Comment: Object.hashCode mirrors memory layout, but `& 0xFFFF0` would give some good bits. Other hashCodes often will be 0 centric positive numbers. Doing some bit rotation, multiplication, taking middle bits might help. Check out math forums from stack overflow.

Comment: @JoopEggen I don't really get what you're suggesting (other than going to the math forums). What's 0xFFF0 and how do I do bit rotation, multiplication etc? What bits are you reffering to anyways - the returned integer value of hashCode?

Comment: "So the input are objects of my node-class." If you control the nodes, why not give them a random weight on construction?

Comment: @CGFoX sorry forget my ramblings, yes, using the original hashCode to uniformly map. That looses information: doing arithmetical operations, maybe shuffling bits and taking some of the bits. Another way would be to serialize the object to bytes, and calculate ones own hash code over them. See **ObjectOutputStream**.

Answer (score 0):

You could actually use random numbers, if

- they are stored along with the objects in a map that is globally accessible or passed around to everyone that needs to generate double "hash" values and
- make sure that each object is looked up in the map and only for not-yet-present ones a new value is generated.

(You might want to wrap that map and the lookup/generate logic in its own class.)

Comment: I thought about it too, but since the graph is dynamic there is nothing globally accessible. And passing it around would be a whole lot of effort because the list would need to be updated every time a new object would be added.
I was hoping for an easier solution with an actual uniformly distributed function.

Comment: What do you mean - "nothing globally accessible"? You could just have a `public static final IDGenerator IDGENERATOR` somwhere, and call `IDGENERATOR.getValue(node)` whenever you need the value. The logic of keeping the map up to date is then completely hidden from the nodes, and keeping a map up to date should add little overhead compared to the hash code generation anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of caveats in your question.

**First**

> I can't use functions or classes like Math.random or Random since that
>   would return different results for the same input.

You can probably use Math.Random with known seed.

```
Random generator = new Random(seed);
double random = generator.nextDouble();
```

**Second**

You mentioned

> My best approach so far was using the Object.hashCode() method and
>   breaking the returned int-value down to a double between 0 and 1.
>   Unfortunately, the distribution of the resulting values is not very
>   uniformly. Lots of values are between 0.1 and 0.3. I guess the
>   hashCode() method isn't unifomrly distributed.

This means the distribution of your input is such that .hashCode() is returning values between 0.1 and 0.3. In your case, the hashing function you'd want to use would depend on the input.

**What could should probably do**

- Look at the distribution of your input to decide a hashing function.
- [Murmurhash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MurmurHash) is known to work well in terms of hash being uniformly distrributed. Check if it works for your case.
- If all else fails, create your custom hashing function similar to the one discussed in this [StackExchange post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/70884/31109).